Rewrite Nested IF functions Excel
I have this formula, and I paste in cells, to give the concatenation of two cells values based on some conditions, it worked fine, until i had to increase the IF functions, and saw that there's a limit.
I do not know how to use Vlookup or the WATCH function. Never used any of this.
I just want this formula to work when I paste it in the cells. I paste it in about more than 200 cells. and it's pretty fast.
I'd appreciate any direct help, so the formula works, I do not know much of excel or vba.
=IF(AND(AQ1<=-6),"-6",

IF(AND(AQ1=-5,AR1>=5),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".5"),

IF(AND(AQ1=-4,AR1<4,AR1>=2),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".2"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-4,AR1<7,AR1>=4),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".4"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-4,AR1>=7),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".7"),

IF(AND(AQ1=-3,AR1<2,AR1>=0),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".0"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-3,AR1<3,AR1>=2),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".2"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-3,AR1<4,AR1>=3),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".3"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-3,AR1<5,AR1>=4),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".4"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-3,AR1<6,AR1>=5),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".5"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-3,AR1<8,AR1>=6),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".6"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-3,AR1>=8),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".8"),

IF(AND(AQ1=-2,AR1<1,AR1>=-1),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".-1"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-2,AR1<2,AR1>=1),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".1"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-2,AR1<3,AR1>=2),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".2"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-2,AR1<4,AR1>=3),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".3"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-2,AR1<5,AR1>=4),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".4"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-2,AR1<6,AR1>=-5),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".5"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-2,AR1<7,AR1>=6),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".6"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-2,AR1<9,AR1>=7),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".7"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-2,AR1>=9),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".9"),

IF(AND(AQ1=-1,AR1<-1,AR1>=-2),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".-2"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-1,AR1<0,AR1>=-1),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".-1"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-1,AR1<1,AR1>=0),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".0"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-1,AR1<2,AR1>=1),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".1"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-1,AR1<3,AR1>=2),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".2"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-1,AR1<4,AR1>=3),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".3"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-1,AR1<5,AR1>=4),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".4"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-1,AR1<6,AR1>=5),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".5"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-1,AR1<7,AR1>=6),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".6"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-1,AR1<9,AR1>=7),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".7"),
IF(AND(AQ1=-1,AR1>=9),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".9"),

IF(AND(AQ1=0,AR1<-1,AR1>=-3),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".-3"),
IF(AND(AQ1=0,AR1<0,AR1>=-1),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".-1"),
IF(AND(AQ1=0,AR1<1,AR1>=0),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".0"),
IF(AND(AQ1=0,AR1<2,AR1>=1),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".1"),
IF(AND(AQ1=0,AR1<3,AR1>=2),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".2"),
IF(AND(AQ1=0,AR1<4,AR1>=3),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".3"),
IF(AND(AQ1=0,AR1<5,AR1>=4),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".4"),
IF(AND(AQ1=0,AR1<6,AR1>=5),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".5"),
IF(AND(AQ1=0,AR1<7,AR1>=6),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".6"),
IF(AND(AQ1=0,AR1<8,AR1>=7),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".7"),
IF(AND(AQ1=0,AR1>=8),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".8"),

IF(AND(AQ1=1,AR1<-2,AR1>=-3),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".-3"),
IF(AND(AQ1=1,AR1<-1,AR1>=-2),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".-2"),
IF(AND(AQ1=1,AR1<0,AR1>=-1),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".-1"),
IF(AND(AQ1=1,AR1<1,AR1>=0),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".0"),
IF(AND(AQ1=1,AR1<2,AR1>=1),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".1"),
IF(AND(AQ1=1,AR1<3,AR1>=2),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".2"),
IF(AND(AQ1=1,AR1<4,AR1>=3),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".3"),
IF(AND(AQ1=1,AR1<5,AR1>=4),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".4"),
IF(AND(AQ1=1,AR1<6,AR1>=5),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".5"),
IF(AND(AQ1=1,AR1<8,AR1>=6),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".6"),
IF(AND(AQ1=1,AR1>=8),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".8"),

IF(AND(AQ1=2,AR1<0,AR1>=-2),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".-3"),
IF(AND(AQ1=2,AR1<0,AR1>=-1),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".-2"),
IF(AND(AQ1=2,AR1<1,AR1>=0),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".-1"),
IF(AND(AQ1=2,AR1<2,AR1>=1),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".0"),
IF(AND(AQ1=2,AR1<3,AR1>=2),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".1"),
IF(AND(AQ1=2,AR1<4,AR1>=3),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".2"),
IF(AND(AQ1=2,AR1<5,AR1>=4),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".3"),
IF(AND(AQ1=2,AR1<6,AR1>=6),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".4"),
IF(AND(AQ1=2,AR1>=6),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".6"),

IF(AND(AQ1=3,AR1<2,AR1>=-1),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".-3"),
IF(AND(AQ1=3,AR1<3,AR1>=0),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".-1"),
IF(AND(AQ1=3,AR1<3,AR1>=1),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".0"),
IF(AND(AQ1=3,AR1<4,AR1>=2),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".1"),
IF(AND(AQ1=3,AR1<5,AR1>=3),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".2"),
IF(AND(AQ1=3,AR1<6,AR1>=5),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".3"),
IF(AND(AQ1=3,AR1>=5),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".5"),

IF(AND(AQ1=4,AR1<5,AR1>=0),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".-4"),
IF(AND(AQ1=4,AR1<6,AR1>=2),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".0"),
IF(AND(AQ1=4,AR1>=2),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".2"),

IF(AND(AQ1=5,AR1>=0),CONCATENATE(AQ1,".0"),

IF(AND(AQ1>=6),"6",

AQ1)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))

From this Image. You'll see that I give values, and not the sheet giving me values, The values that i give to be imputed in sheet AO are most times NOT dependent on AR, but the Values are always dependent on AQ. and from the results of the IF conditions, the values that have been pre configured by me are entered into AO. This is the Reason why I think that the MATCH and INDEX functions will not be useful in this formula
*** 

A lot of your tests have the same outcome, e.g. CONCATENATE(AQ1,".5") is the result in 7 distinct scenarios, so you could consolidate those 7 IF() functions into one as this image illustrates, but this would change the order of evaluation of your function, so you would have to test it with your data to confirm whether it produces the desired results.

It's not just 6 - I just used that as one example! (there are 6 instances of CONCATENATE(AQ1,".6") etc)

You mean I could group all of them that has the same scenarios, yes I get it. But as long as it would change the order of my evaluation, it's a no go area for me.

It might be worthwhile for you to explain the logic of what you're showing us. I'm at a loss to explain why rows 2 and 3 give different results in column AR when AO2, AO3, AQ2 and AQ3 are all the same

@SpectralInstance consolidating it worked perfectly, just the way I wanted it. And it didn't change the evaluation order. Thanks so much. You actually answered the question.

Only that, when I tried consolidating all, it threw an error, saying too many arguments, so I just did a few. Thanks

You can set up a table with every combination of inputs, such as:

and use a formula to check if the conditions are met, for example something like:
=F2+
    INDEX(D2:D3,
        MATCH(1,
            (F2=A2:A3) *
            (G2<B2:B3) *
            (H2>=C2:C3),
            0)
    )


This formula adds a value from cell F2 to a value returned by the INDEX function. It uses multiple criteria to determine which value to retrieve from a range (D2:D3) using the MATCH function. Here's a breakdown of each component:

F2 +

The formula starts with the value in F2 and adds the result of the INDEX function. You can use CONCATENATE instead.


INDEX(D2:D3, ...)

The INDEX function retrieves a value from the range D2:D3. The row number to retrieve is determined by the MATCH function.


MATCH(1, ..., 0)

The MATCH function finds the position of the first occurrence of 1 in the array produced by the logical criteria. The 0 at the end specifies an exact match.


Logical Criteria:

(F2=A2:A3)

Checks if the value in F2 matches any value in the range A2:A3. This results in an array of TRUE or FALSE values.


(G2<B2:B3)

Checks if the value in G2 is less than corresponding values in B2:B3. This results in an array of TRUE or FALSE values.


(H2>=C2:C3)

Checks if the value in H2 is greater than or equal to the corresponding values in C2:C3. This also produces an array of TRUE or FALSE values.




(F2=A2:A3) * (G2<B2:B3) * (H2>=C2:C3)

These conditions are multiplied together. In Excel, TRUE is treated as 1 and FALSE as 0. Therefore:

If all conditions are TRUE for a specific row, the product is 1.
Otherwise, the product is 0.




MATCH(1, ..., 0)

The MATCH function looks for the first 1 in the resulting array (where all conditions are TRUE) and returns its position. This position is used as the row number for the INDEX function.




How It Works:

The formula looks for the first row in the ranges where:

The value in A2:A3 equals F2.
The value in G2 is less than the value in B2:B3.
The value in H2 is greater than or equal to the value in C2:C3.


Once a matching row is found, the corresponding value from D2:D3 is retrieved.
This value is then added to the value in F2.


Thanks for the response, but how does this work? I need to know how it works for me to be able to use it. Mine checks the value of AQ, and if On the same row, the value AR is met, with the condition  then concatenate the two cells, (with a "." Char and write it in the cell where the formula is written) else write the value of AQ there. You need also to note that I paste this in so many cells. So please explain yours, so I can totally understand it. Thanks @Michal

I need to know where to put AR, AQ and the conditions, and then concatenate, if you look closely, I NORMALLY have 2 conditions, then on the final one of a number  it becomes one condition. Can you edit your answer using only two columns please if possible AQ and AR.

@Pachino - you should be able to easily do it yourself and it's going to be a good test for you to see if you understand how the formula works.

I have edited the question, so you'll understand it better with the image attached @Michal. I appreciate your efforts

@Pachino then rework what you have been shown to suit your situation - best way to learn.
